# relation function in models using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables.one is user,second is event and third is eventParticipants.Here i have 3 type of users. one is organizer its status is 1,second is participant its status is 2,third is subparti which organizer and particiant can create and their status is 3.when participant  register a event it stores in a eventParticipant table.Also if participant registering event by his participant it also save on the same eventParticipant table.Now my problem comes in the part of listing this registeration in participant dashboard.Here i need to list both participant and his subparti registration detail.But i cnoont get the whole data.I listed my tabel structure below:

### 1.user

id name email status createdBy

1   A    AA    2       0

2   A1   AA1   3       1

3   A2   AA2   3       2

### 2.EventPArticipants

id eventid eventowner name email

1. 25      18        A    AA
2. 27      14        A1   AA1
3. 22      17        A2   AA2

---

when i am listing in the participant home.blade.php i need:

### Name event    date       action

A     Event1  04/05/2020  show

A1    Event2  04/08/2020  show

A2    Event3  04/05/2020  show

here i used model relation but i dont get subpartis.
eventPArticipants.php

```
public function active(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventParticipants', 'email', 'email');
    }
```

Comment: How can u call EventParticipants class from eventPArticipants.php its same i guess

Comment: $user=User::where('id',Auth::User()->id)->with('partis')->get();
        dd($user[0]->partis);
        foreach($user[0]->partis as $u){
            $regEvents=EventParticipants::where('email',Auth::User()->email)->Orwhere('email',$u->email)->with('organizs')->get();
            
        }

Comment: here in 'partis' i get subparti, but i think the regevents gets wrong

Comment: if participant is loged and see the list will be his and his subpartis if events registered

Comment: show your partis function

Comment: User.php
public function partis() {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'createdBy');
    }

Comment: here in eventParticipants table the name and email is same as on the user table

Comment: in user.php model
public function active(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventParticipants', 'userId', 'id');
    }
    public function partis() {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'createdBy')->with('active');
    }

Comment: and in controller
$user=User::where('id',Auth::User()->id)->with('partis')->get();

Comment: the active is not show anything

Comment: What you actually want?? I thaught you need the user data according with the participants data

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is eventowner, is the the user_id ??? if its the user_id then
use  hasManyThrough like this

```
public function partis(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough ('App\Models\Event',
                                      'App\Models\EventParticipants',
                                      'eventowner' or user_id,
                                      'id', // Foreign key on Event table...
                                      'id', // Local key on user table...
                                      'id' // Local key on EventParticipants
                                      );
    }
```

pull the data like This in your controller

```
$data = User::with('partis')
              ->where('additional logic')
              ->get();
```

You can use callback as well... make Sure Your pivot table (EventPArticipants) is well
By this you can get exact events of the user

Comment: the relation partis[] is null

Comment: i dont need the event table, i just need the auth:user and its subpartis from user and if they have recoreds in eventparticipants table if they are exists.

Comment: this userid is the user who register the event